# GIT bash on Windows: VIM doesn't find Python3

Tags: python, windows, git, vim, mingw-w64

Good Morning, my VIM isn't able to find my Python installation on windows.
Thanks in advance for all who take the time to read this question :)

**My Current Setup**
I'm currently running VIM 8.0.27 inside GIT Bash on windows (unmodified 64bit setup from https://git-scm.com/download/win). Furthermore i've installed the 64bit version of Python 3.5.2 in the following directory: "C:/Python35/"
I've added "C:/Python35/" and "C:/Python35/Scripts/" to my **PATH variable**.
VIM seems to be compiled with Python support as the version text includes
"+python/dyn" and **"+python3/dyn"**.

**My Problem**

It appears to me that VIM is not able to find my python installation.
When I call ":echo has('python')" or **":echo has('python3')"** it returns 0.
I get the following error message when I try to start VIM with python plugins installed: **"UltiSnips requires py >= 2.7 or py3"**.

**Long Term Goal**

My goal is to get Greg Hurrel's VIM configuration up and running on Windows 7 (https://github.com/wincent/wincent). Among other things it requires Python and Ruby. I would also appreciate hints regarding other (better) ways to achieve this.

**Details**

$ which python35.dll

```
/c/Python35/python3.dll
```

in vim:  ":echo $PATH"

```
/c/Users/JannikV/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/JannikV/bin:/c/Python35/Scripts:/c/Python35:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Windows/system32: ...
```

$ vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Oct 12 2016 13:28:14)
Included patches: 1-27
Compiled by <alexpux@gmail.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl/dyn        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim80"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 - I/usr/include/ncursesw  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -pipe -fstack-protector -pipe -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe        -lm    -lncursesw -liconv -lacl -lintl   -pipe -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt`
```

Answer (score 1):

After much effort I finally got python to work with gvim 8.0 on windows 10.
The secret is that it has to be python version 2.7.0 (higher versions may work, 2.7.13 does not).

I also have python 3.6 installed to use when I actually do python programming.

python 2.7.0 is not in my **PATH** environment variable, but I suspect that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The bitness of your vim build must match the bitness of your Python version. AFAIK, the bitness of the vim that comes with Git for Windows is 32-bit, so it won't talk to 64-bit Python.

Check if running 32-bit Windows version of terminal vim from Git Bash:

```
:echo has('win32unix')
```